# The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'id'

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I'm newbie with Nhibernate. Hope I can find the answer here.
This is my class:

```
public class PaymentAudit : EntityBase<int>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public PaymentAudit() { }
    public  System.Guid PaymentStateId { get; set; }
    public  System.DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
    public  Payment Trn { get; set; }
    public  PaymentSaga PaymentSaga { get; set; }
    public  ProcessState ProcessState { get; set; }
    public  PublishState PublishState { get; set; }
    public  System.Nullable<short> ChgCount { get; set; }
    public  string UserName { get; set; }

    protected override void Validate()
    {
    }
}
```

This is my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="Praweda.Interface.Framework.Model.Payment"
        assembly="Praweda.Interface.Framework.Model">

  <class name="PaymentAudit" table="PaymentAudit" lazy="false" >
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="PaymentStateId" column="PaymentStateId" />
      <key-property name="DateStamp" column="DateStamp" />
      <key-property name="ProcessState" column="ProcessState" />
    </composite-id>
    <id name="PaymentState">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <column name="PaymentStateId" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </id>    
    <id name="ProcessState">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <column name="ProcessState" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    <id name="DateStamp">
      <generator class="identity" />
      <column name="DateStamp" sql-type="datetime" not-null="true" />
    </id>   
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="PaymentStateId">
      <column name="PaymentStateId" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="PaymentStateId">
      <column name="PaymentStateId" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="ProcessState">
      <column name="ProcessState" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="ProcessState">
      <column name="ProcessState" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="PublishState">
      <column name="PublishState" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="PublishState">
      <column name="PublishState" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" name="Trn">
      <column name="Trn" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="Trn">
      <column name="Trn" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="ChgCount">
      <column name="ChgCount" sql-type="smallint" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="UserName">
      <column name="UserName" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I'm trying to add the repository assembly in session factory, here's the code

```
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.AddAssembly("MyProject.Nhibernate.Repository");

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        config.Configure();

        _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

give me error :
The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `composite-id` element followed by an `id` element.  You can't have both.

Use `composite-id` when the primary key in your table spans multiple columns.

Next to that, you can only have one single `id` element.  It defines how your entity is uniquely identified.
For properties, you should use the `property` element.

It might be helpfull to check out the NHibernate documentation:
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping

Comment: yup, removing id element solve my problem. But i have to change the one of key-property in composite-id to key-many-to-one. this is a foreign key. My first project with ORM n must learn alot. Thanks!